# How to finish angular observable before value changes check?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable, angular-observable

I am creating a search bar similar to Angular Autocomplete but I can't get my array in time.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IngredientService } from '../ingredients-shared/ingredient-service.service';
import { Ingredient } from '../ingredients-models/ingredient';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {map, startWith} from 'rxjs/operators';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-ingredients',
  templateUrl: './list-ingredients.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-ingredients.component.css']
})
export class ListIngredientsComponent implements OnInit {

  options: string[] = ['Angular', 'React', 'Vue'];

  mylist: Ingredient[];


  myControl = new FormControl();
  filteredOptions: Observable<Ingredient[]>;


  constructor(public ingredientService: IngredientService) { }

    ngOnInit() {

    this.ingredientService.getAllIngredients().subscribe( (ingredients: Ingredient[]) => {
      this.mylist = ingredients
    });

    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(
        value => 
        this._filter(value))
    );
  }


  private _filter(value: string): Ingredient[] {

    console.log(value)
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.mylist.filter(ingredient => ingredient.ingredient_name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }

  displayIngredientName(subject: Ingredient){
    return subject ? subject.ingredient_name : undefined
  }

}
```

As you can see I need to populate mylist before checking for value changes in the form and I can't figure out how to finish beforehand.

I tried using async/await but I don't wanna use async in ngOnInit. I have also inserted the form changes inside the subscribe but of course that only happens once so it would not work.

Any advice? Thanks

Edit: This is the HTML:

```
    <form>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input type="text" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="myControl"/> 
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayIngredientName">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let ingredient of filteredList$ | async" [value]="ingredient" >
                {{ingredient.ingredient_name}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine both observables into single stream, since they depends on each other. User can start typing before data is loaded, with your approach search values entered before data is loaded will be ignored.

You could achieve it like this:

```
const ingredients$ = this.ingredientService.getAllIngredients();
const searchValues$ = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(''), map(val => val.toLowerCase()));
const filteredList$ = combineLatest(ingredients$, searchValues$)
                      .pipe(map(([list, searchVal]) => list.filter(item => item.ingredient_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchVal))));
```

Then just use async pipe in your template. And don't forget OnPush change detection. It is also good idea to use debounceTime, to limit search operations on fast typing.

Comment: Why is OnPush change detection needed? Shouldn't myControl.valueChanges detect changes to the input? Also it doesn't seems to be working, did I implemented something wrong in my template? Added the HTML to the question.

Comment: Do your ingredientService really returns array of values? You can log what happens with 'tap' operator, then you will see where it stucks. Post your problem to stackblitz, then I'll give more detailed help.

Comment: OnPush is used to prevent change detection on every event, every setInterval, setTimeout, ajax response etc... In general it is good practice to use it. If you generate components with schematics, you'll get it by default.

Comment: If I subscribe to filteredList$  and populate the results then it works, yes it returns a list of ingredients.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. If only thing you have to do is to display filtered data, you don't have to subscribe. Async pipe does that for you. If it doesn't work without explicit subscription, then something is wrong with your code.